# Problema no código em C executando uma função

Tags: c

Olá, estou com um problema neste código. Estou implementando a função do bubble sort. Mas algo curioso acontece ao executar este código. A variável n que indica a quantidade de espaços do vetor na função main é modificada após executar a função bubbleSort(). E eu não estou entendendo o motivo dessa modificação já que não passa o ponteiro da variável n para a função de ordenação. Alguém poderia por favor me explicar o motivo?

O n sempre modifica para o maior valor do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ASC(int x, int y) {
    return x < y;
}

int DSC(int x, int y) {
    return x > y;
}

void bubbleSort(int *list, int start, int size, int cmp(int, int)) {
    int cont, hold;
    for(; start < size-1; start++) {
        for(cont = 0; cont < size-start; cont++) {
            if(cmp(list[cont+1], list[cont])) {
                hold = list[cont];
                list[cont] = list[cont+1];
                list[cont+1] = hold;
            }
            printf("hold = %d\n", hold);
            printf("cont = %d\n\n", cont);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int vetor[] = {1,8,7,14,5};
    int n = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    bubbleSort(vetor, 0, n, ASC);

    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fiz um teste em minha máquina (Linux Fedora 24) e o valor de `n` *não* é modificado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gmorikawa essa questão realmente foi difícil de entender, mas ai vai:

O conceito de ponteiros é o mesmo conceito dos arrays em c, quando os dados estão armazenados na pilha (stack) eles são sequencias na memória.

Imagine a seguinte situação: você declarou um array com 5 índices e logo após um inteiro (fora do array, mas ainda na sequencia da pilha) ambos na stack:

```
int vetor[] = {1,8,7,14,5};
int n = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);
```

Sendo assim o sistema operacional organizou seus dados da seguinte forma (fictício, mas com propósito educacional)

```
Índice       | Valor | End. Memória
int vetor[0] |   1   | 0x000
int vetor[1] |   8   | 0x001
int vetor[2] |   7   | 0x002
int vetor[3] |  14   | 0x003
int vetor[4] |   5   | 0x004
int n        |   ?   | 0x005
```

E na sua função BubbleSort você acessa durante a iteração o índice atual (iterador) e o índice + 1.

Ao chegar no último elemento do array o próximo elemento acessado corresponde em tipo (int), mas não faz mais parte do array;
Este elemento é acessado sequencialmente na memória pois é um ponteiro válido para um inteiro (aponta para a variável "n").

O valor é testado e segue o mesmo processo de sort...

Caso o valor de vetor["ultimo_indice" + 1] seja alterado a variável "n" receberá o valor atribuído a ele.

C é muito bom, te dá inúmeras possibilidades. Mas as vezes estas possibilidades geram um erro bem diferente do que era esperado (no caso índice fora do intervalo para o array).

Espero ter conseguido auxiliar.