# Qual o motivo do erro "The operator / is undefined for the argument" neste código?

Tags: java

```
 double t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
 double t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.print("\n Tempo Total: "+ (t2-t1)/Double.valueOf(1000)+ " segundos");
```

Ao compilar a terceira linha, correspondente ao `System.out.println`, dá um erro:

> Unresolved compilation problem:   The operator / is undefined for the
>   argument type(s) double, Double

Comment: Está executando normalmente, veja: https://ideone.com/p9a7b3

Comment: Pode colocar a parte dos `import`s desse arquivo Java?

Comment: Eu sou iniciante. quais são os imports que devo colocar e onde devo colocar, por favor? no seu arquivo tem esses: import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;  Coloquei mas não funcionou.

Comment: não alterei exatamente nada no seu código, só copiei e colei sem a necessidade de nenhum import. Rodou de boas.

Comment: Que esquisito amigos, aqui não roda de jeito algum.Da o mesmo erro.  The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Double

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Double

Comment: Pedi os import porque poderia ser que seu Double não era o Double do Java e sim um outro que você importou sem querer.

Comment: Após ler [o comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149425/qual-o-motivo-do-erro-the-operator-is-undefined-for-the-argument-neste-c%c3%b3dig#comment308616_149425) do @sullyvan.nunes resolvi compilar o código original e tudo deu certo também ([exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/AAaaS1)). Dito isso já vi erros semelhantes acontecendo no Eclipse, Jaspersoft Studio, etc. Acredito que algo na cadeia de compilação pode estar se comportando diferente do compilador padrão da Oracle.

Comment: Qual é a versão do Java? Isso só funciona a partir do Java 5 (lançado em 2004). Se o seu Java for uma versão mais dinossáurica, isso não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado galera, to usando o eclipse é o java e o mais recente!.

Comment: Ontem foi o dia dos erros esquisitos. Essa e [essa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149413/problema-no-c%c3%b3digo-em-c-executando-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o) no mesmo dia? Raios cósmicos devem ter nos atingido feio ontem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que <s>o compilador</s> alguma ferramenta na sua cadeia de *build* está se perdendo na hora de fazer [*unboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) do tipo `Double` para o primitivo `double`, o que é necessário para possibilitar a divisão. Para ser mais didático, existem regras claras para *unboxing* e *widening* que você encontra em livros especializados da certificação Java SE Programmer. Compilando seu exemplo diretamente com o compilador da Oracle ([veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/AAaaS1)) tudo funcionou conforme esperado, o que me leva a crer que alguma das suas ferramentas está causando o problema.

Dito isso, tente o seguinte:

```
System.out.print("\n Tempo Total: "+ ((t2-t1)/ 1000.0d)+ " segundos");
```

Dessa forma você está usando um literal do tipo `double` e nenhuma forma de *unboxing* é necessária.

Comment: Tempo Total: 0.0 segundos Parabéns Anthony!, é isso mesmo, muito obrigado!, resolveu! :D

Comment: Se eu fizer pra  double p1 = 1 / Double.valueOf(array.length - 1); Como fica?   double double p1 = (1 /(array.length - 1)d);???

Comment: Thiago, dá dúvida nunca use `valueOf` (esse método retorna um `Double` e não um `double`). Se você quiser valores fracionários use literais `double` e/ou *casting*: Por exemplo: `double p1 = 1.0d / (array.length -1);` ou `double p1 = 1 / ((double) array.length -1);`

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 0):

Tente fechar o parêntese mais uma vez fazendo com que sua operação fique isolada, desta forma:

```
double t1 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
double t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.print("\n Tempo Total: "+ ((t2-t1)/Double.valueOf(1000))+ " segundos
```

Comment: Continuou com o mesmo erro Meu amigo :(, mas obrigado pela tentativa, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Double